# Can't replace my regex matches

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I can filter files, I can can stream the matches of my regex ...
However, I need to remove exactly that, from a large file.

Regex:`^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$`

```
sed -e '/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$/d/ /g' file
```

only streams the matches but does not replace/cut them.

*I can seach for files, containing matches, also works.*

**What is formula to get it working?**

Comment: what did you try until now?

Comment: I did split the large file, delete the partial files, which did contain my regex and assemble them reverse to the whole. However, that is more likely a slower / more dirty process over endless partial files

Comment: @Olaf Just to be clear, you want to remove the patterns matching your regex from the file. Is that correct?

Comment: YES.   In fact, that are emails, where attachments get removed, with the aging of the mails, as a huge number of clients abuses the mail-servers as storage. After 8 years and longer, several with attachments forwarded, no 35MB email with the attachments is useful. I only want to preserve the textual content

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using a Perl-compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) with `sed`.  The `sed` utility only knows Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) by default (or Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) when used with `-E` on most systems).

I also don't think that the `sed` syntax is correct, but it's difficult to read because the expression in the question seems to have extra `*` in them. You appear to want to strip out the multipart divider in an email message, but you don't seem to care about matching these up correctly (matching a start of one multipart part to the corresponding end divider). If the `sed` syntax was corrected, the expression would likely delete the full contents of the emails, or combine all attachments into the body of the message.

The PCRE expression

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

is the same as the ERE (to be used with `sed -E`)

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3})?=$
```

and using this with `d` (which you appear to be doing) to would delete those lines, but the trailing `/ /g` in your `sed` command is an error. Removing `/ /g` would likely have the effect of combining all attachments into the body of the email.

If you want to strip attachments of email messages (as [indicated in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505419/cant-replace-my-regex-matches#comment933084_505419)), I would not try to do it with `sed` but with a proper email message parser.

Examples of how to go about doing this may be found in the following related questions:

- [Remove/Delete Attachments from email server (IMAP)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174707/remove-delete-attachments-from-email-server-imap)
- [Detaching an attachment in Mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313395/detaching-an-attachment-in-mutt)
- [Best way to archive attachments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/best-way-to-archive-attachments)

Personally, I would write a Perl script similar to the one in the first linked question/answer above.  Just remember to always run test runs of such scripts on *copies* of you mailboxes, just in case you make mistakes.

The `fdm` mail tool is able to *filter* messages based on the number and/or size of attachments, which may be handy as a way of filtering out large email messages from archived mailboxes.

Comment: "I also don't think that the sed syntax is correct, but it's difficult to read because the expression in the question seems to have extra * in them." - yes, this regex matches in gedit AND bluefish, as well other apps exactly the parts, I want/need remove. (eyGf7wbBqo6apbkvAzbR1Vjmt+W5hhQl5F6dSawrzVJrpvKs49ynhnzis5xS6u500JTlpZW89isn
iC/kzCI13njNSQXrQNvltXaQ9WPJp6aXNJCqO6RAHORyfzqKXTZIJN1xK0sIHVTyPwrO01q2zovR ......) Until now, I just split the files on ss1='------=_NextPart_'
ss2='------=_Part_'
ss3='----_'
ss4='--=_'
ss5='--'

Comment: @Olaf Yes, it may well do if those tools understand PCRE, but `sed` does not.

Comment: to split the huge files. Obviously, when splitting here and delete the file parts containing the regex, there 5 lines missing. I neither manage to break before or after the regex - empty lines, neither I get the base64 codes (see the regex out)

Comment: @Olaf As I mentioned in my answer, I would not do this with a tool that is not email-aware.

Comment: "The fdm mail tool is able to filter messages" - That I can do via find, sort desc. A plain text mail of 1 mb is not between, 2100k small - 800k is huge for a mail, without attachment. I only look currently at files exceeding 30MB, containing 29 attached mails containing attachments

Comment: No, they are running exim - open source (WHM) - so they expect, someone will  mess around in structure tree' .. find -P /home/*/*/flat-dir $one_year | while read OLDMAIL;


do

echo "${OLDMAIL}"
pwd
if grep -q 'ds1' "${OLDMAIL}"; then
echo "yes" ..." <- here looping over the files/mails, looking, where/how to split. As I can del the base64, I have to see, one of the many options, where the file/mail splits

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed -E "s/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$//g" file
```

and double-check the output. The `-E` HAVE to be capital. `-e` doesn't work.

Once you are sure it works, use `-iE` instead to make the changes directly into the file

Comment: I will try that in a while and give you a thumb up/down. Thx a lot

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 69: Invalid preceding regular expression